# Zend - populate combobox with database returned data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-studio

I try to do it this way:

```
public function init()
{
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */

    $sets_table = new Optionals_Model_DbTable_Sets();

    $set = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('set');
    $set ->setLabel('Alegeti setul de optionale:');

    foreach ($sets_table->getSets() as $value) {
        echo $value->cod_set_optional;
        $set->addMultiOption($value->cod_set_optional);
    }

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Continua');

    $this->addElements ( array (
            $set,
            $submit
    ) );
}
```

where getSets() from the DbTable looks like this:

```
public function getSets()
{
    $select = $this->select();
    $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);
    if (!$rows) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find!");
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

I've seen this kind of doing it [HERE](http://www.peacocksuit.com/blog/tag/zend_form_element_select/), but it doesn't work. The echo works fine, but the combobox is not populated. Is there something wrong in my code or what?

Thank you!
Sorin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addMultiOption($option, $value)` [requires two parameters and you are giving it only a value.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select)

you should do this :

```
 foreach ($sets_table->getSets() as $set) {
        $set->addMultiOption($set->id , $set->value);
    }
```

make sure your getSets returns both an id and a value from your table.

Comment: but I only want to add the ID into the combobox

Comment: i did it this way **$set->addMultiOption($value->cod_set_optional, $value->cod_set_optional);** because I need only the code...thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your using fetchAll method just use

```
$list->addMultiOptions(usermodel::getInstance()->getusers());
```

whole code would be like this

```
$list      =   new Zend_Form_Element_Select('users');
$list->setLabel('Select a user')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addValidators(array(array('notEmpty',true, array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Please select a User')))));
$list->addMultiOptions(usermodel::getInstance()->getusers());
die($list);
```

and in the model

```
class usermodel extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected  $_name               =   'users';
    protected  static $_instance    =   null;

    public function getusers()
    {
        $sql          =     "SELECT us.`id` AS `key`,CONCAT(us.`firstname`,' ',us.`lastname`) AS `value` FROM   
     `users` us 
                            ORDER BY us.`firstname` ASC";  
        return  $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
         if( !isset(self::$_instance) ){
            $instance = new self();
            self::$_instance = $instance;
         }
         return self::$_instance;
    }

}
```